# Nested computed column "Invalid column name" error (T-SQL Column alias)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, alias, calculated-columns

I've create 3 computed columns as alias and then used the aliased columns to calculate the total cost. This is the query:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Id]
      ,[QuantityOfProduct]
      ,[Redundant_ProductName]
      ,[Order_Id]
      ,(CASE 
            WHEN [PriceForUnitOverride] is NULL 
                THEN [Redundant_PriceForUnit]
            ELSE
                [PriceForUnitOverride]
        END
        ) AS [FinalPriceForUnit]

      ,(CASE 
            WHEN [QuantityUnit_Override] is NULL 
                THEN [Redundant_QuantityUnit]
            ELSE
                [QuantityUnit_Override]
        END
        ) AS [FinalQuantityUnit]

      ,(CASE 
            WHEN [QuantityAtomic_Override] is NULL 
                THEN [Redundant_QuantityAtomic]
            ELSE
                [QuantityAtomic_Override]
        END
        ) AS [Final_QuantityAtomic]

         --***THIS IS WHERE THE QUERY CREATES AN ERROR***--
        ,([QuantityOfProduct]*[FinalPriceForUnit]*
  ([Final_QuantityAtomic]/[FinalQuantityUnit])) AS [Final_TotalPrice]


  FROM [dbo].[ItemInOrder]

  WHERE [IsSoftDeleted] = 0
  ORDER BY [Order_Id]
```

The console returns this ERROR message:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 55
Invalid column name 'FinalPriceForUnit'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 55
Invalid column name 'Final_QuantityAtomic'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 55
Invalid column name 'FinalQuantityUnit'.
```

If I remove the "AS [Final_TotalPrice]" alias computed column, no error occurs, but I need the total price. How can I solve this issue? It seems as the other aliases have not been created when the Final_TotalPrice is reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use table aliases in the same select.  The normal solution is CTEs or subqueries.  But, SQL Server also offers `APPLY`.  (Oracle also supports `APPLY` and other databases such as Postgres support lateral joins using the `LATERAL` keyword.)

I like this solution, because you can create arbitrarily nested expressions and don't have to worry about indenting:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 io.Id, io.QuantityOfProduct, io.Redundant_ProductName,
       io.Order_Id,
       x.FinalPriceForUnit, x.FinalQuantityUnit, x.Final_QuantityAtomic,
       (x.QuantityOfProduct * x.FinalPriceForUnit * x.Final_QuantityAtomic / x.FinalQuantityUnit
       ) as Final_TotalPrice
FROM dbo.ItemInOrder io OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT COALESCE(PriceForUnitOverride, Redundant_PriceForUnit) as FinalPriceForUnit,
             COALESCE(QuantityUnit_Override, Redundant_QuantityUnit) as FinalQuantityUnit
             COALESCE(QuantityAtomic_Override, Redundant_QuantityAtomic) as Final_QuantityAtomic
     ) x
WHERE io.IsSoftDeleted = 0
ORDER BY io.Order_Id ;
```

Notes:

- I don't find that `[` and `]` help me read or write queries at all.
- `COALESCE()` is much simpler than your `CASE` statements.
- With `COALESCE()` you might consider just putting the `COALESCE()` expression in the final calculation.

Comment: Neat solution, plus you included APPLY

Answer (score 2):

You can't use an alias in the same select. What you can do is find the value in subquery and then use it outside in the expression (or may be repeated the whole case statement in your expression). Also, use `COALESCE` to instead of `CASE`.

```
select t.*,
    ([QuantityOfProduct] * [FinalPriceForUnit] * ([Final_QuantityAtomic] / [FinalQuantityUnit])) as [Final_TotalPrice]
from (
    select top 1000 [Id],
        [QuantityOfProduct],
        [Redundant_ProductName],
        [Order_Id],
        coalesce([PriceForUnitOverride], [Redundant_PriceForUnit]) as [FinalPriceForUnit],
        coalesce([QuantityUnit_Override], [Redundant_QuantityUnit]) as [FinalQuantityUnit],
        coalesce([QuantityAtomic_Override], [Redundant_QuantityAtomic]) as [Final_QuantityAtomic]
    from [dbo].[ItemInOrder]
    where [IsSoftDeleted] = 0
    order by [Order_Id]
    ) t;
```